# Libre Office is opening without menus

Tags: libreoffice, 14.04, gtk

[image: Libre Office]

Libre Office is opening without menus ... How can i solve this ?-I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64-

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands. Hope it works.

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

Also visit:
http://sourcedigit.com/8157-customize-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-11-must-tweaks/
http://sourcedigit.com/8266-15-powerful-unity-tweak-tool-customizations-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and only Writer was behaving like this (no window decoration).

I closed/reopen it to get a working window with menus.